# Zend Pagination : How ot get arrray of data

Tags: zend-framework, zend-paginator

I am using zend paginator. I am getting following structure by using $this->paginator:

```
(
   [_cacheEnabled:protected] => 1
    [_adapter:protected] => Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array Object
        (
            [_array:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                         (
                         )
                           )

            [_count:protected] => 8
        )

    [_currentItemCount:protected] => 
    [_currentItems:protected] => 
    [_currentPageNumber:protected] => 1
    [_filter:protected] => 
    [_itemCountPerPage:protected] => 4
    [_pageCount:protected] => 2
    [_pageRange:protected] => 
    [_pages:protected] => 
    [_view:protected] => 
)
```

I have accessed $this->paginator using for loop and every thing is working fine. but now I  want to access only  [_array:protected] => Array value and want to split the result in 3 sets using array_slice. But I am not able to access that array values. I have tried by type casting it to array but not getting it.

Comment: You cannot access protected properties directly. What specifically are you trying to access? Why are you trying to split the array?

Comment: I have a open book like structure. I have to show data on that. 4 on each side. I was thinking to slice the array  and show. I can not use one foreach and perform logic inside that loop due to designing problem. I need two arrays of result..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array` class has a `getItems()` method which does exactly that : slice the `_array` container.

So if you want the first third of the result set you can do :

```
$adapter = $paginator->getAdapter();
$results = $adapter->getItems(0, $adapter->count() / 3);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you get stuck again with Zend try taking a look at library sources, the code is well-written and not overly complicated. You'll always find a way.